# No me reconoce el comando NG - Angular en Cygwin

Tags: angular, cmd, windows10, angular-cli

Quise actualizar Angular, siguiendo los pasos de esta página:

[How to upgrade Angular CLI to the latest version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43931986/how-to-upgrade-angular-cli-to-the-latest-version)
Más preciso esto:

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Pero después de realizar eso no me reconoce la variable **ng** en **Cygwin**, me lo reconoce en la terminal propia de **Windows** y la terminal de **Visual Studio Code**.

En Cywgin, luego de ejecutar:

```
ng v
```

me sale lo siguiente:

```
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm/node_modules/node/bin/node: línea 1: This: no se encontró la orden
```

En esa ubicación, *C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node\bin*, lo que hay son dos archivos:
Nombre: **node**
Tipo de archivo: **archivo**

Nombre: **node.exe**
Tipo de archivo: **aplicación**

Y aclaro que Angular si se actualizó.

Lo que intenté hasta ahora fue lo siguiente:

Pensé que el problema era en las variables de entorno. Agregué, por las dudas, la siguiente línea:

> C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli

Pero sigue sin andar. Supongo que esas variables de entorno son para la terminal de Windows.

Comment: Si estás usando windows y los archivos se corrompieron por una mala nstalación o actualización del angular. Tendrías que eliminar estas dos carpeta: `C:/Users/{username}/AppData/Roaming/npm` y `C:/Users/{username}/AppData/Roaming/npm-cache` y vuelve a reinstalar los módulos.

Comment: @Synay toda la carpeta npm? Pregunto porque eso abarca MUCHOS archivos que tengo dentro y no creo que sea lo correcto, pero si vos estas seguro y supongo que conoces, lo hago. En npm-cache tengo muy pocas cosas, asi que no se que tan importante sera.

Comment: Sabes de que archivos son, cierto? son módulos que ocupas para tus proyectos, puedes eliminarlos e instalarlos las veces que quieras.

Comment: Sisi, todos los paquetes instalados con el comando npm, pero como son muchos los que he instalado al momento me parece medio raro. Luego de hacer eso que tengo que hacer?

Comment: ¿No prefieres poner todos los pasos en una respuesta, por si funciona marcar tu respuesta como recomendada?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para solucionar problemas como archivos corruptos.

Tienes que seguir estos pasos:

**1°** Elimina esta carpeta`C:/Users/{username}/AppData/Roaming/npm`donde se alojan los módulos por defecto.

**2°** Elimina la carpeta que aloja el caché de `npm` ubicado en `C:/Users/{username}/AppData/Roaming/npm-cache`

**3°** Instala nuevamente el angular: `npm install -g @angular/cli`

Recuerda que tu `{username}` es tu carpeta admin.

Comment: Antes de hacerlo, estás seguro que ese es el problema? Me sigue pareciendo raro porque "ng" me anda en las demás consolas excepto en Cygwin. De igual forma ya me encuentro anotando cada paquete que tengo instalado para después volver a instalarlos,

Answer (score 1):

Posiblemente solo necesite hacer un ajuste como se muestra en este ejemplo:

1. `me@Laptop7:~ $ npm --version`

   6.4.1
2. `me@Laptop7:~sudo npm uninstall -g angular-cli`
3. `me@Laptop7:~sudo npm install -g @angular/cli`

Ahora solo teclee `ng version` y eso debe resolver su problema.

Comment: No, no se resolvió el problema :/

Comment: Usted puede darme mas informacion porque a ciegas es dificil.

Comment: Volvi al mismo punto, donde ya estaba. No se realiza ningun cambio. Me vuelve a salir lo de: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm/node_modules/node/bin/node: línea 1: This: no se encontró la orden

Comment: Que version de NodeJS tiene usted instalada?

Comment: Node 12.14.1 ------------- NPM 6.13.6

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso yo lo solucioné agregando la carpeta npm a la lista de variables de entorno.
[image: Le abres a variables de entorno]

[image: Le seleccionas path y das en editar]

[image: Le das a nuevo y pones ese path]

al parecer mi problema era que todos los ejecutables para los comandos estaban en esa carpeta.
[image: Foto de donde estaban mis ejecutables]